# Get the blog page URL set in Options

Tags: theme-development, functions, permalinks

I have set the blog to be a different page other than the home page.

I want to have a link from single.php to this blog page.

Is there any function that pulls out URL for the blog ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As of WordPress 4.5 you can use:

```
get_post_type_archive_link( 'post' );
```

This handles the logic of getting the correct URL regardless of whether posts show up on the homepage or in a specified page.

Answer (score 94):

To build on Sagive's answer, you'll want to wrap the ID in get_permalink() to get the actual link.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ); ?>">Our Blog</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

Best way to check the option before setting the permalink is as follows:

```
if ( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) {
   echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) )).'">'.esc_html__( 'Blog', 'textdomain' ).'</a>';
} else {
   echo '<a href="'.esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ).'">'.esc_html__( 'Blog', 'textdomain' ).'</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `get_option` of `page_for_posts` to get the page ID to either assign it to a variable or to echo it if you wish to do so.

```
<?php $postsPageId = get_option('page_for_posts'); ?>
<a href="index.php?p=<?php echo $postsPageId; ?>">Our Blog</a>
```

For additional information of the defualt get_option visit: [Option Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference)

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the Hugh Man that it is better to check the option before echoing the link, but it is possible to set the static page as a front page and leave the posts page empty. In this case, the link will just point to the home URL. A better approach is to provide a fallback to the posts archive page. Something like this:

```
function slug_all_posts_link() {
    if ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ) {
        if ( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) {
            echo esc_url( get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) );
        } else {
            echo esc_url( home_url( '/?post_type=post' ) );
        }
    } else {
        echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to `esc_url` the `get_permalink` and `home_url` functions