# Link for the page archive for posts, like using custom post types with get_post_type_archive_link

Tags: posts, permalinks, archives, links

I am trying to get the page to list all my posts (post type = `post`) in archive.

I can do this with custom post types, with `get_post_type_archive_link()`, but using `get_post_type_archive_link('post')` to get the page url of all posts doesn't work the same way.

Also using `get_permalink()` or `get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) )` returns only the link of one post.

Example:

I would like to get a link like `www.example.com/posts/` or other, in a similar way as the custom post type, when using `get_post_type_archive_link('news')`, retrieves `www.example.com/news/`.

Can I get a list of posts other than in the home page? Is this possible?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `get_post_type_archive_link` works with `post` as of several versions ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the blog page URL set in Options](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50509/get-the-blog-page-url-set-in-options)

Comment: I had already check that question, but .Well, for some reason the `get_post_type_archive_link`

Comment: You can also look at [`get_post_type_archive_link` source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.3/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1122) to see how it gets that link in the case of `post`, it incorporates your other example.

Comment: @Milo thanks for the reply and link, but for some reason the `get_post_type_archive_link` is returning the URL of the root of website (`www.example.com`) and not something like (`www.example.com/news/`) . Has that suppose to return that? I can to distinguis from the front_page or home page! At the moment I have made a workaround using `add_query_arg` but probably is a good practice to use WP core functions dedicated for this. I have the WordPress version 4.7.3.

Comment: Correction: `www.example.com/news/` to `www.example.com/post/`. Probably I have to check the source code to learn a bit more. Thanks!

Comment: What is Front Page and Posts Page set to under admin Settings > Reading?

Comment: Thanks for your time! In "Front page displays" it display a static page. 
in option "Front page" it as a page selected and in option "Posts page" I have nothing selected. Do tell me that I need to make a page for the posts?

Comment: If I select a page, in option "Posts page", it does return the page that I have selected there (example: `www.example.com/sample-page/`).
I most say that has expecting a behavior more like custom posts `www.example.com/post/`, but probably this is not cause for WordPress.
It's a bit disappointing, but it is what it is, and it will have to do. In this case put in a answer so I can atribute as the right answer, or something that I can vote. Either way this as very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use a shortcode:

```
function shortcode_article_list() {
  $posts_array = get_posts( array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish') );
  $output = '<ul>';
  foreach ($posts_array as $post) {
    $a = explode(' ', $post->post_date);
    $output .= '<li><a href="' . home_url('/') . $post->post_name . '.html">' . $post->post_title . '</a> (' . $a[0] . ')</li>';
  }
  $output .= '</ul>';
  return $output;
}
add_shortcode('article_list', 'shortcode_article_list');
```

Perhaps there's something you can use from it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But unfortunately this is not what I need! Probably I didn't explain my self very well (I added a example to the question), but I need to get the link. Example: www.example.com/posts/ in the same way as the get for custom post types www.example.com/custom_post_type/ .